# Open current directory as project in sublime?

Tags: gnome, sublime-text

So I finally have sublime all working through terminal the way I like it, but I'd like to be able to `mkdir`, `cd` into the directory (just creating a top-level website file tree), and open sublime through the terminal, and have the entire directory opened up as a "project" where I can see the file structure in the left pane.

I've had this working on mac and windows menu, but for the life of me I can't figure it out on my linux box.

Running Sublime 2.0.2, Raring (13.04), and GNOME 3.6.3.1

Any ideas?

Comment: I tried setting up an alias `alias subl="subl --add &` and re-sourced `~/.bashrc` but it still isn't working. Do I have to remove a symlink first? Where would that be stored if installed via ppa?

Comment: I've also tried removing the alias and running `subl --add --new-window . &` from bash, which only opened sublime, without adding the directory. Interestingly, it said `--add` was an invalid command, though it's in the documentation; so I ran `subl --help`, and it launched sublime without providing help in-terminal. What is going on?

Comment: For some reason I had to `unalias subl` multiple times, refreshing gnome after each before the alias dropped from bash. After the alias was gone, I was able to troubleshoot with sublime's terminal help. In the end, I was able to get it working with the following command: `subl --add --new-window . &`

I hope my public failure and learning session helps someone else!

Comment: It's always great to see users troubleshooting their own problems and sharing their findings. However, you should probably rephrase your last comment as an answer to the question and mark it as resolved. This will make it easier for future users to find your solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason I had to unalias `subl` multiple times, refreshing gnome after each before the alias dropped from bash. After the alias was gone, I was able to troubleshoot with sublime's terminal help. In the end, I was able to get it working with the following command: `subl --add --new-window . &` I hope my public failure and learning session helps someone else!